# SOAPAction not setting properly - Java

Tags: java, web-services, saaj

I am trying to add SOAPAction to my SOAP web request.

Following is my code:

```
    return (TPResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(genTP, message -> {
        ((SaajSoapMessage)message).setSoapAction("http://tempuri.org/GenerateParam");
    });
```

Expectations are that this code should add a separate header field in my HTTP request as `SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GenerateParam"`. But following is what final packet is formed:

```
POST /myscripts/script.php?somedetails HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: application/soap+xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; 
    action="http://tempuri.org/GenerateParam"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_73
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 578
```

Please note that rather than adding separate HTTP Header it has modified `Content-Type` and added `action` with value in it. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I just changed the Soap Protocol of my `SaajSoapMessageFactory` from `SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL` to `SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL` and it started working properly.